# How to convert 'GtkWidget' type in gtk+ to the 'Gtk::Widget' type in gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I simply tried this.

```
GtkWidget* oldwnd = new GtkWidget();
Gtk::Widget wnd(*oldwnd);
```

But it does not compile.

Can anybody tell me how to type cast the types in gtk+ to the corresponding types in gtkmm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `Gtk::Widget* wnd = Glib::wrap(oldwnd)`?

[documentation says](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html)

```
Gtk::Widget* wrap (GtkWidget* object, bool take_copy=false);
```

Comment: Furthermore, this part of your example makes no sense because you should use a gtk_*_new() function to instantiate a GTK+ type: GtkWidget* oldwnd = new GtkWidget();